# Limsup of $A_n = \{ \text{"heads" not seen in first $n$ flips}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I understand mathematically what $\limsup A_n$ means, it's the set of outcomes that occur infinitely many times. However, I'm trying to intuit the meaning via a simple example:
Let $A_n$ be a sequence of events such that $$A_n = \{\text{"heads" not seen in first $n$ flips}\}$$
What would $\limsup A_n$ be in this case? In this case isn't the event space for $A_n$ simply $\{\text{True}, \text{False} \}$ And so $\limsup A_n = \{\text{True}, \text{False} \}$?

Perhaps this isn't the greatest example, so any other elementary examples to understand the meaning of limsup for events would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really... $A_n =\{\text{True},\text{False}\}$ has simply no sense. Notice that $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ for all $n$. Then $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n=\{\text{"Head" never appear}\}.$$

Comment: @Surb gotcha, this is a trivial example then. Do you know of a better example to grasp the concept?

Comment: I don't understand your misunderstand... $\limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n$ is simply the event "$A_n$ occurs infinitely often" what can be simply translated mathematically by $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{m\geq n}A_m...$$